# Decorator for partial application /and/or/ currying: How to determine if mandatory arguments are supplied?

Tags: python, functional-programming, decorator

I've been tinkering with decorators lately and (as an academic exercise) tried to implement a decorator that allows for partial application *and/or* currying of the decorated function. Furthermore this decorator should be optionally parameterizable and take a kwarg `asap` which determines if the decorated function should return as soon as all mandatory args/kwargs are aquired (default: `asap=True`) or if the decoratored function should keep caching args/kwargs until the function is called without arguments (`asap=False`).

Here is the decorator I came up with:

```
def partialcurry(_f=None, *, asap: bool=True):
    """ Decorator; optionally parameterizable; Allows partial application /and/or/ currying of the decorated function F. Decorated F fires as soon as all mandatory args and kwargs are supplied, or, if ASAP=False, collects args and kwargs and fires only if F is called without args/kwargs. """

    def _decor(f, *args, **kwargs):

        _all_args, _all_kwargs = list(args), kwargs

        @functools.wraps(f)
        def _wrapper(*more_args, **more_kwargs):

            nonlocal _all_args, _all_kwargs # needed for resetting, not mutating
            _all_args.extend(more_args)
            _all_kwargs.update(more_kwargs)

            if asap:
                try:
                    result = f(*_all_args, **_all_kwargs)
                    # reset closured args/kwargs caches
                    _all_args, _all_kwargs = list(), dict()
                except TypeError:
                    result = _wrapper
                return result

            elif not asap:
                if more_args or more_kwargs:
                    return _wrapper
                else:
                    result = f(*_all_args, **_all_kwargs)
                    # again, reset closured args/kwargs caches
                    _all_args, _all_kwargs = list(), dict()
                    return result

        return _wrapper

    if _f is None:
        return _decor
    return _decor(_f)


### examples
@partialcurry
def fun(x, y, z=3):
    return x, y, z

print(fun(1))     # preloaded function object
print(fun(1, 2))  # all mandatory args supplied; (1,1,2); reset
print(fun(1)(2))  # all mandatory args supplied; (1,2,3); reset

print()

@partialcurry(asap=False)
def fun2(x, y, z=3):
    return x, y, z

print(fun2(1)(2, 3))  # all mandatory args supplied; preloaded function object
print(fun2())         # fire + reset
print(fun2(1)(2))     # all mandatory args supplied; preloaded function object
print(fun2(4)())      # load one more and fire + reset
```

I am sure that this can be generally improved (implementing this as a class would be a good idea for example) and any suggestions are much appreciated, my main question however is how to determine if all mandatory args/kwargs are supplied, because I feel like to check for a `TypeError` is too generic and could catch all kinds of `TypeError`s. One idea would be to define a helper function that calculates the number of mandatory arguments, maybe something like this:

```
def _required_args_cnt(f):
    """ Auxiliary function: Calculate the number of /required/ args of a function F. """
    
    all_args_cnt = f.__code__.co_argcount + f.__code__.co_kwonlyargcount
    def_args_cnt = len(f.__defaults__) if f.__defaults__ else 0
    return all_args_cnt - def_args_cnt
```

Obviously unsatisfactory..

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Since you used the FP tag: Currying is a concept to simplify the function API by restricting them to single argument functions that behave more like mathematical ones. What you are doing is quite the opposite: You obfuscate their API. I don't know whether this makes sense from an imperative perspective, but it breaks with everything FP stands for.

Comment: @scriptum Thank you for your reply! "What you are doing is quite the opposite: You obfuscate their API." I can see how *the combination* of currying and partial application functionality might be an antipattern, but what you say would also apply for and argue against partial application which is (as I understand) a classical FP concept.

Comment: AFAIK partial application comes from imperative programming. FP folks often use this term to refer to a curried function which isn't yet applied to all its arguments, but this is a completely different thing. When I started with FP I loved this `f(x) (y, z)` pattern too. I wish someone had told me that it is mostly useless in terms of FP.